# can I create a custom iterator the iterates over one sequence then another (chain doesnt work)

Tags: rust

I have a `struct Folder`. I have a method called `contents`. I want that method to return an object that supports `IntoIterator` so that the caller can just go

```
for x in folder.contents(){
...
}
```

The `Item` type is (since this is what the hashmap iterator returns - see a little lower)

```
(&OsString, &FileOrFolder)
```

where `FileOrFolder` is an enum

```
enum FileOrFolder{
   File(File),
   Folder(Folder)
}
```

The iterator itself needs to first enumerate a `HashMap<OSString, FileOrFolder>` owned by the folder and then second, enumerate a `Vec<File>`. The `Vec` of files is created on the fly by the contents `fn` or by the `IntoIterator` call, whatever works. I tried simply using `chain` but quickly realized that wasn't going to work. So my rough sketch of what I am trying to do is this:

```
// the iterator 
pub struct FFIter {
    files: Vec<FileOrFolder>,
    files_iter:Box<dyn Iterator<Item=FileOrFolder>>,
    dirs: Box<dyn Iterator<Item =  (&OsString, &FileOrFolder)>>,
    dirs_done:bool
}

// the thing returned by the contents fn
struct FolderContents{
   folder:&Folder
}
// make it iterable
impl IntoIterator for FolderContents {
    type Item =(&OsString, &FileOrFolder);
    type IntoIter = FFIter;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        let files  = self.folder.make_the_files()
        FFIter {
            files: files, // to keep files 'alive'
            files_iter: files.iter(),
            dirs: Box::new(self.hashmap.iter()),
            dirs_done:false
        }
    }
}
impl Iterator for FFIter {
    type Item = (&OsString, &FileOrFolder);
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(&OsString, &FileOrFolder)> {
          None // return empty, lets just get the skeleton built
    }
}

impl Folder{
   pub fn contents(&self) -> FolderContents{
     FolderContents{folder:&self}
  }
}
```

I know this is full of errors, but I need to know if this is doable at all. As you can see I am not even trying to write the code that returns anything. I am just trying to get the basic outline to compile.

I started arm wrestling with the lifetime system and got to the point where I had this

```
error[E0658]: generic associated types are unstable      
  --> src\state\files\file_or_folder.rs:46:5
   |
46 |     type Item<'a> =(&'a OsString, &'a FileOrFolder);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #44265 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265> for more information
```

Which kinda sucked as that is what the compiler said I should do.

I am happy to keep ploughing away at this following the suggestions from the compiler / reading / ... But in the past I have posted a question along these lines and been told - 'of course it can't be done'. So should I be able to make this work?

The Folder type is not `Copy` and expensive to clone. The File type is simple `(string and i64)`, `Copy` and `Clone`

I know I could simply make the caller call two different iterations and merge them, but I am trying to write a transparent replacement module to drop into a large existing codebase.

If somebody says that `chain()` should work that's great, I will have another go at that.

EDIT Jmp said chain should work,

heres what I tried

```
pub fn contents(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = (&OsString, &FileOrFolder)> + '_> {
    let mut files = vec![];
    if self.load_done {
        for entry in WalkDir::new(&self.full_path)
            .max_depth(1)
            .skip_hidden(false)
            .follow_links(false)
            .into_iter()
        {
            let ent = entry.unwrap();
            if ent.file_type().is_file() {
                if let Some(name) = ent.path().file_name() {
                    files.push((
                        name.to_os_string(),
                        FileOrFolder::File(File {
                            name: name.to_os_string(),
                            size: ent.metadata().unwrap().len() as u128,
                        }),
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Box::new(
        self.contents
            .iter()
            .map(|(k, v)| (k, v))
            .chain(files.iter().map(|x| (&x.0, &x.1))),
    )
}
```

but the compiler complains, correctly, that 'files' get destroyed at the end of the call. What I need is for the vec to be held by the iterator and then dropped at the end of the iteration. Folder itself cannot hold the files - the whole point here is to populate files on the fly, its too expensive, memory wise to hold them.

Comment: `chain` should work, but you will need to make sure that both iterators have the same `Item` type or use `map` to convert one (or both) to the appropriate type.

Comment: @Jmb, well thats precisely what I tried to do (map & chain) and couldnt make it work. I will try again

Comment: @Jmb nope, I dont see how to do it, the vec of files is created on the fly. I will update the Q to show what I tred

Comment: "created on the fly" and "iterator with references in the item" don't usually go together at all.

Comment: @SebastianRedl - I 100% know that. I am asking for advice what to do, I am sure I can store the 'on the fly ' vec in the iterator object itself. Thats what I was asking for help with originally but Jmp said I should just use chain

Comment: "in the iterator object itself" - Unfortunately that's not good enough. Iterators cannot return references to their insides. The specification of the trait simply doesn't allow it in a sound way.

Comment: @SebastianRedl so this is not doable then. I guess we need generators, but then generators are just sugar over hand craftable code, so it must be doable. Hence the question

Comment: It's totally doable, just not with the specific interface that the `Iterator` trait guarantees.

Comment: @SebastianRedl could you provide an answer then, even a rough sketch of how to do it, doesnt have to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

You claim that `files` is populated on the fly, but that's precisely what your code is *not* doing: your code precomputes `files` before attempting to return it. The solution is to *really* compute `files` on the fly, something like this:

```
pub fn contents(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = (&OsString, &FileOrFolder)> + '_> {
    let files = WalkDir::new(&self.full_path)
        .max_depth(1)
        .skip_hidden(false)
        .follow_links(false)
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map (|entry| {
            let ent = entry.unwrap;
            if ent.file_type().is_file() {
                if let Some(name) = ent.path().file_name() {
                    Some((
                        name.to_os_string(),
                        FileOrFolder::File(File {
                            name: name.to_os_string(),
                            size: ent.metadata().unwrap().len() as u128,
                        }),
                    ))
                } else None
            } else None
        });
    self.contents
        .iter()
        .chain (files)
}
```

Since you haven't given us an MRE, I haven't tested the above, but I think it will fail because `self.contents.iter()` returns references, whereas `files` returns owned values. Fixing this requires changing the prototype of the function to return some form of owned values since `files` cannot be made to return references. I see two ways to do this:

- Easiest is to make `FileOrFolder` clonable and get rid of the references in the prototype:

```
pub fn contents(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = (OsString, FileOrFolder)> + '_> {
    let files = ...;
    self.contents
        .iter()
        .cloned()
        .chain (files)
```

- Or you can make a wrapper type similar to [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) than can hold either a reference or an owned value:

```
enum OwnedOrRef<'a, T> {
    Owned (T),
    Ref (&'a T),
}

pub fn contents(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = (OwnedOrRef::<OsString>, OwnedOrRef::<FileOrFolder>)> + '_> {
    let files = ...;
    self.contents
        .iter()
        .map (|(k, v)| (OwnedOrRef::Ref (k), OwnedOrRef::Ref (v))
        .chain (files
            .map (|(k, v)| (OwnedOrRef::Owned (k),
                            OwnedOrRef::Owned (v)))
}
```

You can even use `Cow` if `FileOrFolder` can implement [`ToOwned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html).

Comment: ty - when I said 'on the fly' I mean that the data is not a field in the struct. It is generated on demand. It would be trivial if files was a member of Folder

Comment: I see what you are doing, ty.